# Mail-in database

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have this scenario (this is an old story of mail-in)

This is a company where have many Domino Mail-in databases. One  for every branch.

Every person in every branch has a personal Notes Email.

The company policy is that each person of the branch can not send email to an external account (internal yes), so I need to use the mail-in database.

I tried with the rules of Domino to perform a block (in the rule you can set the Sender field to track the mail), but it does not seem possible because unfortunately, when a user sends an email from a mail-in database (mail9.ntf template) the sender field is the username.

I know about [Team Mail box project](http://teammail.openntf.org/), but this is an old project and I have some problems with HTML outgoing mail and it doesn't work on the web.

I tried looking for a solution, customizing the standard Mail9.ntf template and I discovered that the library "CoreEmailClasses" with the function QuerySave method is executed **Me.m_noteUIMemo.Send()** 
I have tried to change this code copying the backend document into mail.box the mail...but this doesn't work because it is more complicated (there are TMP field...and I observed that when you use `.send()` into mail.box the RichText is a MIME-RT) .

The only solution that I have found is to save the email and later with a scheduled Sign Agents to Run on Behalf Of the mail-in user that sends the email (solution that I do not like because is not in realtime).

Do you have any other ideas?

**UPDATE FOR INOTES**

I've found into the FORMS9_x.nsf the subform
*Custom_MailMemoDictionary_Lite* that contains this code. Now I need to understand how to use it

```
 <NotesComment>
//Use s_MDNToFrom to change the From field in outgoing email.  If
//s_MDNToFrom is set, need to also provide From field.  Uncomment out the
//dictionary to enable this
</NotesComment>
<NotesComment>
<NotesDictionary>
    <notesvar name=s_MDNToFrom value={"1"}>
    <notesvar NAME=From value={"Custom From Field"}>
</NotesDictionary>
</NotesComment>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will solve your problem but we have found that setting the **Mail-in name** (item name **FullName**) in the **Mail-in Database** document to a hierarchical name allows us to setup the owner of the mail-in database as that user. Then mail sent from that database is from the **mail-in name** sent by the actual user.

For example: use a name like: **Branch1 Email/Organization** and set the internet email to **branch1.email@oraganization.com** and then set the owner of the target database to **Branch1 Email/Organization**

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

deletes the contents of the subform and paste the following code

```
  <NotesDictionary>
    <notesvar name=s_MDNToFrom value={"1"}>
    <notesvar NAME=From value={Principal}>
  </NotesDictionary>
```

kind regards